# How to improve my code (C/ Objective C) Ping Pong game

Tags: objective-c, c

I'm new to C and Objective C. Therefore I am doing small and easy tasks.
In this one, I am simulating a Ping-Pong game. My code is doing everything it should do but I am not happy about its structure.

Things my code should cover:

- Random pick Winner / Loser
- By hitting 21 Winner gets honored

but I am not happy with the point that, if both have the count of 20 the game should continue until one is two points ahead.
I am pretty sure there are better ways to complete that.

Thank you

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int player1 = 0;
    int player2 = 0;



    while (player1 < 21 && player2 < 21){

            if(player1 == 20 && player2 == 20){
                do{
                    int pick = arc4random()%2;

                    if (pick == 0) {
                        player1 = player1 + 1;
                    } else if (pick == 1){
                        player2 = player2 + 1;
                    }
                }while (player1 == player2 - 2 || player2 == player1 - 2);
            }

        int pick = arc4random()%2;

        if (pick == 0) {
            player1 = player1 + 1;
        } else if (pick == 1){
            player2 = player2 + 1;
        }

    }

    if (player1 > player2){
       NSLog(@"Player 1 has %i points and Player 2 %i", player1, player2);
    } else if (player2 > player1){
        NSLog(@"Player 2 has %i points and Player1 %i",player2, player1);
    }


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does it work or not? If no, how?

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I would improve this code by using a `players` array instead of a `player1` and `player2` variable. `players` would have two items, the first being indexed with 0 (player1) and the second being indexed with 1.

This way you will be able to change

```
                if (pick == 0) {
                    player1 = player1 + 1;
                } else if (pick == 1){
                    player2 = player2 + 1;
                }
```

to

```
players[pick]++;
```

Another problem is that even in the case when the score is 20-20, you are still randomizing, which is unnecessary. Moving the randomizing code into a function which returns 0 or 1 would help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Just reduce the score of both players to 19 when both players have the equal score of 20.

```
while (player1 < 21 && player2 < 21){               
    int pick = arc4random()%2;    
    if (pick == 0) {
        player1 = player1 + 1;
    } else if (pick == 1){
        player2 = player2 + 1;
    }        
    if(player1 == 20 && player2 == 20){
        player1 = 19;
        player2 = 19;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would extract the code to choose whether player won to a method, and call the same code for both player1 and player2. another cosmetic change is to use switch case instead of if else.
code will look like this:

```
static int player_won( int player_score, int other_player_score )
{
    if ( player_score < 21 )
        return 0;
    //player score is 21 or more.

    if ( other_player_score < 20 )
        return 1;

    //other player score is more than 20, must have at least 2 points more
    int diff = player_score - other_player_score;

    if ( diff >= 2 )
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int player1 = 0;
    int player2 = 0;

    while ( 1 )
    {
        if ( player_won( player1, player2 ) ||
             player_won( player2, player1 ) )
            break;

        int pick = arc4random()%2;
        switch ( pick )
        {
        case 0:
            player1++;
            break;
        case 1:
            player2++;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (player1 > player2){
       NSLog(@"Player 1 has %i points and Player 2 %i", player1, player2);
    } else if (player2 > player1){
        NSLog(@"Player 2 has %i points and Player1 %i",player2, player1);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't stop if the difference is less than two points:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int player1 = 0;
    int player2 = 0;

    while ((player1 < 21 && player2 < 21) || abs(player1 - player2) < 2) {
        int pick = arc4random()%2;

        if (pick == 0) {
            player1 = player1 + 1;
        } else if (pick == 1) {
            player2 = player2 + 1;
        }
    }

    if (player1 > player2){
       NSLog(@"Player 1 has %i points and Player 2 %i", player1, player2);
    } else if (player2 > player1){
        NSLog(@"Player 2 has %i points and Player 1 %i", player2, player1);
    }
}
```